# Doctrine Entity Manager instances

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I am new to Doctrine Symfony framework and want to understand how entity manager works in multi-threaded environment.

I have service class called `ProxyDelegator` which is called every time service method is called.

```
app.ProxyDelegator:
    class: Acme\SampleBundle\Controller\ProxyDelegator
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

This class will receive entity manager passed as above and create the transaction and then it invoke the service method with reflection. This will help developers not to handle transaction management every time.

So the flow will be Controller `->` `ProxyDelegator` (Create Transaction from entity manager) `->` Service Method (invoked from `ProxyDelegator` using reflection).

My question is will it create the new entity manager for every new client request? If not how should I handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `EntityManager` **IS NOT** a singleton so, everytime you invoke it, you'll get a brand new one.

If you want to try yourself, just print out result of [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php)